# Any efficient way to solve anagrams?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.* ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String  str1 = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String str2 = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    
    char[] temp = str1.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(temp);
    str1 = new String(temp);
    
    temp = str2.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(temp);
    str2 = new String(temp);
            
    if(str1.equals(str2) == true) System.out.println("Anagrams");
    else System.out.println("Not Anagrams");
}
```

The above code has passed all the test cases, i thought to explore the code for a better approach.

But as it takes longer time and converting to charSequence, sorting and all. Is there any better approach to solve it?

Thank you.